# Why does zooming out too far cause my object to vanish?

Tags: 3d-view

If you think the title of this question sounds hilarious, you aren't alone, but that's what's happening. I've built a large complex shape (crude description, I know), and now find out that I can only view it from certain angles and certain distances. If I zoom out too far it vanishes, just as if it was passing through a pressure curtain to another world. The object is generated entirely using python code.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: ok, scaling the object down gets around the problem.  so far.  it still vanishes when you get too far away.. fascinating.  I'm used to solidworks.. which has it's own limitations..

Comment: change the clip distance

Comment: @susu hi, changing the clip distance will likely work.  I have now noticed (hard not to), that my question has been edited, and informed that other answered questions provide the info I need, and ... I'm not actually sure what I should do or what I'm -supposed- to do.  what I was intending to do was to come back in a week or so when my mind will be motivated to study this part of blender again, absorb the information, thank everybody, and be on my way.

Comment: When you are ready and motivated with more questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely your viewport clipping end distance is too short. Press N in object mode to bring up the tool menu and change it under "view".

[image: ClipDistance]